# Ubuntu 15.10 on Windows Host VirtualBox Problem

Tags: virtualbox, 15.10, squashfs

I install Ubuntu 15.10 on Windows 10 host on VirtualBox, on first reboot after installation complete(the one Ubuntu wants) there is an error like this:

```
SQUASHFS error: Unable to read fragment cache block [....]
```

After I shutdown the virtual machine and boot again, it works, but it's an error that no one want to see I guess.

Is it only me or is this a general bug? How can I solve this?

P.s. No problem on Ubuntu 14.04.3.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu installation discs don't setup a Squashfs volume. What you are seeing is an error message caused while reading from the installation disc. This is unusual for virtual machines where you just mount the ISO. This may be an issue with handling the software correctly and may not be reproducible (if you found a way to reproduce it either VirtualBox or Ubuntu developers may be interested in a bug report), which is why it was gone on the next boot. Just check that the installation disc is not mounted to the virtual machine and it should boot as usual.

Comment: You intended to say the installation disc is not ejected in 15.10?

Comment: Sorry wrong sentence, no I mean the disc is ejected in both.